# Замена frameset на div. Проблема верстки

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка

Есть старый код с frame. Подскажите пожалуйста как разметить используя div и css?

```
<frameset name="xxx" rows="74,*,35" border="no" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="xxx" src="./xxx.html" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <frameset name="xxx" cols="*,300" frameborder="yes" border="0" framespacing="1">
            <frame name="xxx" src="./xxx.html" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
                <frameset rows="*,170" border="0" framespacing="1">
                    <frame name="xxx" src="./xxx.html" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
                    <frame name="xxx" src="./xxx.html" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
                </frameset>
        </frameset>
        <frameset cols="*,0,0,0" noresize="" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
            <frame name="xxx" src="./xxx.html" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="">
        </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Можете более конкретно сказать что хотите в итоге получить и что вы пробовали сделать?

Comment: @Arsen, хочу код с frame заменить полностью на div. Т.е. мне нужна аналогичная разметка - только с div.

Comment: за iframe слышали?

Answer (score 5):

В общем виде на вопрос не будет однозначного ответа. Поскольку фрейм позволяет отображать на одной странице сразу несколько других страниц, то возможны такие варианты:

1. Заменить `<frame>` на `<iframe>`, если подгружать другие самостоятельные страницы всё же необходимо. Пример:

```html
<div class=page>
  <div class=page__one>
    <iframe src="page/page-one.html" width="500" height="100"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class=page__two>
    <iframe src="page/page-two.html" width="500" height="100"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Подгружать аяксом содержимое этих страниц. Пример:

```js
$(function() {
  $.get("page/page-one.html", function(data) {
    $(".page__one").html(data);
  });

  $.get("page/page-two.html", function(data) {
    $(".page__two").html(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=page>
  <div class=page__one></div>
  <div class=page__two></div>
</div>
```

3. Скопировать код из этих страниц и просто вставить его в разметку имеющейся. Пример:

```html
<div class=page>
  <div class=page__one>
    <p>Існує багато варіацій уривків з Lorem Ipsum, але більшість з них зазнала певних змін на кшталт жартівливих вставок або змішування слів, які навіть не виглядають правдоподібно. Якщо ви збираєтесь використовувати Lorem Ipsum, ви маєте упевнитись в тому, що всередині тексту не приховано нічого, що могло б викликати у читача конфуз.</p>

    <!-- предположим, что содержимым файла page-one.html был один параграф с текстом -->
  </div>
  <div class=page__two>
    <p>На відміну від поширеної думки Lorem Ipsum не є випадковим набором літер. Він походить з уривку класичної латинської літератури 45 року до н.е., тобто має більш як 2000-річну історію.</p>

    <p>Річард Макклінток, професор латини з коледжу Хемпдін-Сидні, що у Вірджінії, вивчав одне з найменш зрозумілих латинських слів - consectetur - з уривку Lorem Ipsum, і у пошуку цього слова в класичній літературі знайшов безсумнівне джерело.</p>

    <!-- предположим, что содержимым файла page-two.html были два параграфа с текстом -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы забыли про SSI :) Вставить страницы с того же сервера можно через ssi <!--#include virtual="/page_one.html"-->

Answer (score 0):

Судя по rows у вас во фреймах, вам лучше подойдут не `<div>`, a `<table>`.
Я не берусь с разбегу представить, что у вас там за результат на экране, поэтому конкретный код не напишу. Поиграйтесь сами с rowspam и colspan атрибутами.
А вставить файлы **с того же сервера** вы можете через ssi (если у вас apache).
То есть вместо `<frame name="xxx" src="./xxx.html" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="">`
пишите `<!-- include virtual="./xxx.html"-->`
Поддержка ssi должна быть [включена на апаче](http://www.tdoc.ru/c/web/apache/ssi-server-side.html).